# Spring batch process is getting invoked in BUILD step only via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: spring-batch

I have written a spring batch job and trying to deploy it via our jenkins pipeline.. This pipeline first build the code , create image and then deploy to kubernetese.

In my batch job, I am looking for a file in some specific directory and if the file is not there, our process sends an email.

I am observing one unique thing, whenever my Jenkins pipeline is running, after build step , I am receiving an email for the file unavailability whereas it should send an email or process the file based on its schedule. It seems like the process is getting triggered or invoked in build step only.

Is there any configuration that is required to invoke on the process on its schedule time only in spring batch and not while building ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, you need to set the property `spring.batch.job.enabled` to `false`, because by default, Spring Boot executes all jobs in the application context [on startup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-spring-batch-running-jobs-on-startup).